# it is a binary search code and i m not able to figure out the problem

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code.The code is running but not getting the right results.
For ex- searching 3 in the program is getting output "not found" even though present.

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Bsearch(int arr[],int item,int n)
{
 int low,mid,up;
 low=0;up=n-1;
 while(low<=up && item!=arr[mid])
 {
     mid=(low+up)/2;
     if(item==arr[mid])
        return mid;
     else if(item<arr[mid])
        low=mid+1;
     else
        up=mid-1;
 }
 return -1;


}
int main()
{
    int index,item;;
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  cout<<"enter search item\n";
  cin>>item;
    index=Bsearch(arr,item,9);
    if(index!=-1)
    cout<<"element found at position"<<(index+1);
    else
    cout<<"element not found";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger or put some prints in to see what's happening? This website isn't really designed to help you *find* your bugs.

Comment: You're also using `mid` before it has been assigned a value, resulting in Undefined Behavior. (Also, the `&& item!=arr[mid]` part of the while test is unnecessary.)

Comment: @ 1201ProgramAlarm   yeah correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
if(item==arr[mid])
        return mid;
     else if(item<arr[mid])
        low=mid+1;
     else
        up=mid-1;
```

just change the conditon of choosing `low` and `up` index according the value of mid index `arr[mid]` like:

```
 if(item==arr[mid])
    return mid;
 else if(item<arr[mid])
    up=mid-1;
 else
    low=mid+1;
```

OR change this condition `else if(item<arr[mid])` into `else if(item > arr[mid])` and your code will work fine.

```
if(item==arr[mid])
        return mid;
     else if(item > arr[mid])
        low=mid+1;
     else
        up=mid-1;
```

*N.B: `while(low<=up && item!=arr[mid])` in this line, you're using `mid` in `arr[mid]` before it has been assigned a value, resulting in Undefined Behavior. (Also, the `&& item!=arr[mid]` part of the while test is unnecessary.) **Credit: 1201ProgramAlarm***